# Copy-Item not working with Remote PowerShell to copy files from network share to local drive on remote server

Tags: powershell, powershell-remoting, invoke-command, copy-item

```
Set-ExecutionPolicy -ExecutionPolicy Bypass
$webServers = "remoteservername1"

$deploymentCredentials = Get-Credential


Invoke-Command -ComputerName $webServers -Credential $deploymentCredentials -ScriptBlock {


$appVersionDirectory = "C:\Test"
```

The New-Item creates the directory without a problem:

```
New-Item -ItemType directory -Path $appVersionDirectory
```

The Copy-Item does not error, but will not copy any files

If I run this same Copy-Item command directly on the remote server, it works!

```
$sourceFiles = "\\sourceserver\DeploymentSource\shared\*"
Copy-Item  $sourceFiles -Destination $appVersionDirectory
```

}

Comment: Here's [an article on the two-hop problem](https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/heyscriptingguy/2013/04/04/enabling-multihop-remoting/) that you are likely running into. Note that CredSSP has some security risks to it. It's probably just better to "push" the files to the server prior to Invoke-Command.

Comment: Thank you!    I ended up using "Resource-Based Kerberos Constrained Delegation" described in this article that I found from the link you provided. https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/ashleymcglone/2016/08/30/powershell-remoting-kerberos-double-hop-solved-securely/

Comment: Correction.  I ended up pushing the files prior to the Invoke-Command.  The  "Resource-Based Kerberos Constrained Delegation" approach was still giving me fits and only working part of the time.  Thanks again for your response to my question today.